# Getting error while debugging a C program on pointers

Tags: c, arrays, linux, pointers, gdb

Here is the c code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[]={0,1,2,3,4};
    int*p[]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};
    int**ptr=p;
    ptr++;

    printf("%d , %d  ",*ptr-a , **ptr);
    *ptr++;
    printf("\n%d , %d  ",*ptr-a , **ptr);
    *++ptr;
    printf("\n%d , %d ",*ptr-a , **ptr);
    ++*ptr;
    printf("\n%d , %d ", *ptr-a , **ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: the gdb error highlighted in black??]

I am unable to understand the error and what should be amended in the code.

Comment: You didn't let debugger execute line 8. I guess that's the reason you are getting this error.

Comment: Yes that works. Thank you.  I didn't know how break points work..

Comment: You need to cast `*ptr - a` to `int`, because the resulting type is `ptrdiff_t`: http://ideone.com/CfjqzO Also the `*` in `*ptr++;` is unnecessary.

Comment: Ok thanx .. mch . I will do that.

Comment: BTW, the message `Warning: Source file is more recent than executable`  should be taken into account. You need to *recompile* your program

Comment: Next time, compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`  and improve the code till you get no warnings

Comment: Okay I will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not yet executed line 8 in gdb.

```
8    int **ptr = p;
```

So till now `ptr` is not defined yet in your program. Hence, can not access it. You can press `n` command in gdb prompt and then follow by `print`

```
(gdb) n 
(gdb) print *ptr
```

Also, your program should have `%ld` instead of `%d` in `printf` as format specifier to silence compiler warning as in

```
printf("%ld , %ld  ",*ptr-a , **ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace %d with %ld then it should be working fine.

You can refer [format specifiers details](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_30.htm) for further clarification on this.

Comment: `*ptr - a` results in a type of `ptrdiff_t`.  `"%ld"` is for `long`.  Since C99, should use `"%td"`.

Comment: It's also worth recommending to add `-Wformat` to the compilation command (or, better, `-Wall -Wextra`).